# Relative paths in unittest python to run tests individually and as a whole

Tags: python, unit-testing, path, pycharm

There are already several answered questions to this topic but actually not addressing my problem.

I'm using PyCharm 2021.2 and I want to be able to run unit tests both, individually and as a whole. This is important because if I have many tests and only some of them fail, I usually debug my code and would like to run only my failed tests to see if my debugging was successful. Only then do I want to re-run all the tests.

My setup is as follows:

[image]

So, for instance, I want to:

1. Right-click the folder `tests` and run all tests in this folder (in my example screenshot, there is only one `test_MyClass.py` but usually here would be many such tests).
2. Right-click an individual test, e.g. `test_MyClass.py`, and run it on its own.

Both possibilities usually work fine. However, when my single tests use some relative paths, for instance, to read some test assets (in my case from the folder `containing_folder/tests/testassets`), only the option 1) works. The option 2) runs into a  `FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory`.

The code to reproduce this behavior is:

MyClass.py:

```
class MyClass:
    _content = None

    def set_content(self, content):
        self._content = content

    def get_content(self):
        return self._content
```

test_MyClass.py:

```
import unittest
import io
from ..MyClass import MyClass


class MyClassTests(unittest.TestCase):
    myClassInstance = None

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.myClassInstance = MyClass()

    def get_file(self, use_case):
        path_to_file = "testassets/" + use_case + ".txt"
        with io.open(path_to_file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
            file = file.read()
            return file

    def test_uc_file1(self):
        file_content = self.get_file("uc_1")
        self.myClassInstance.set_content(file_content)
        self.assertEquals("test1", self.myClassInstance.get_content())

    def test_uc_file2(self):
        file_content = self.get_file("uc_2")
        self.myClassInstance.set_content(file_content)
        self.assertEquals("test2", self.myClassInstance.get_content())
```

It seems that `path_to_file = "testassets/" + use_case + ".txt"` only works as a relative path in the 1) option, but not in the 2) option.

How can I recognize programmatically, which option 1) or 2) I'm starting a test in PyCharm? And which path would then I have to choose for option 2)? I tried `../testassets`, `../../testassets`, `../../`, , `../` but none of them worked for option 2).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found how to accomplish what I want.

1. First of all, I got rid of relative paths when importing. Instead of `from ..MyClass import MyClass` I use simply `from MyClass import MyClass`.
2. Second, my methods `setUpClass` and `get_file` now look like this:

```
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.path = os.path.normpath(os.path.abspath(__file__))  # requires import os
        if os.path.isfile(cls.path):
            cls.path = os.path.dirname(cls.path)
        cls.myClassInstance = MyClass()

    def get_file(self, use_case):
        path_to_file = self.path + "/testassets/" + use_case + ".txt"
        with io.open(path_to_file, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
            file = file.read()
            return file
```

The point is that `os.path.abspath(__file__)` returns a root path of either the *directory* `containing_folder/tests` if I choose option 1) to start all tests or the *filename* `containing_folder/tests/test_MyClass.py` if I choose option 2) to start a single test. In the if statement

```
if os.path.isfile(cls.path):
   cls.path = os.path.dirname(cls.path)
```

I generalize both special cases to get the *root directory* of all the tests and easily find the test assets relative to them.

Comment: Doesn't your language server complain when you want to import `from MyClass import MyClass`?